# Toggle images with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I am working on a project where images move to each corner of the screen on button presses. I need these images to toggle from hidden to shown.

To do this I am using `toggle()` but the issue is that I need the ones that are showing to stay showing until toggled off. Currently when I click one it will show, but if I click another then the one previously shown will disappear and the one I clicked will show; only one image will show at a time.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $('#MyImage');
  $('#NWest').on('click', function() {
    img.css({
      top: '0px',
      left: '0px',
      position: 'absolute'
    });
    $("img").toggle();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var text = $('#MyText');
  $('#NWest').on('click', function() {
    text.css({
      top: '150px',
      left: '245px',
      position: 'absolute'
    });
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $('#MyImage');
  $('#NEast').on('click', function() {
    img.css({
      top: '0px',
      left: '75%',
      position: 'absolute'
    });
    $("img").toggle();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var text = $('#MyText');
  $('#NEast').on('click', function() {
    text.css({
      top: '150px',
      left: '88%',
      position: 'absolute'
    });
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $('#MyImage');
  $('#SEast').on('click', function() {
    img.css({
      top: '560px',
      left: '75%',
      position: 'absolute'
    });
    $("img").toggle();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var text = $('#MyText');
  $('#SEast').on('click', function() {
    text.css({
      top: '710px',
      left: '88%',
      position: 'absolute'
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $('#MyImage');
  $('#SWest').on('click', function() {
    img.css({
      top: '560px',
      left: '0px',
      position: 'absolute'
    });
    $("img").toggle();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var text = $('#MyText');
  $('#SWest').on('click', function() {
    text.css({
      top: '710px',
      left: '245px',
      position: 'absolute'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 30px;
}

.text {
  max-width: 20ch;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 245px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

img {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="North West" id="NWest">
<input type="button" value="North East" id="NEast">
<input type="button" value="South East" id="SEast">
<input type="button" value="South West" id="SWest">
<a href='http://cis337-0217.cisdprogram.com/Index.html'>Return to Index</a><br>
<div class="container">
  <img id="MyImage" src="MyImage.jpg" alt="MyImage" style="width:25%" ;>
  <div class="text" id="MyText"> Lines of text. Lines of text. Lines of text. Lines of text. Lines of text. Lines of text. Lines of text.
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to act on the visibility style.

- Put 4 images in your HTML.
- Give them a class in your CSS for the position.
- For each element, you need to toggle, you can use this homemade function toggleImageVisible().

The following snippet work for 2 buttons:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#NWest').on('click', function() {
    toggleImageVisible('MyImageA');
  });
  $('#NEast').on('click', function() {
    toggleImageVisible('MyImageB');
  });
});

function toggleImageVisible(id) {
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    img.style.visibility = (img.style.visibility === 'visible' ? 'hidden': 'visible');
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 30px;
}

.text {
  max-width: 20ch;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 245px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

img {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.MyImageClassA{
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.MyImageClassB{
  top: 0px;
  left: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="North West" id="NWest">
<input type="button" value="North East" id="NEast">
<input type="button" value="South East" id="SEast">
<input type="button" value="South West" id="SWest">
<a href='http://cis337-0217.cisdprogram.com/Index.html'>Return to Index</a><br>
<div class="container">
  <img id="MyImageA" class="MyImageClassA" src="MyImage.jpg" alt="MyImage" style="width:25%" ;>
  <img id="MyImageB" class="MyImageClassB" src="MyImage.jpg" alt="MyImage" style="width:25%" ;>
  <div class="text" id="MyText"> Lines of text. Lines of text. Lines of text. Lines of text. Lines of text. Lines of text. Lines of text.
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```